# How to Replace my Android Studio 4.1.0 with Android Studio Canary

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I want to start with Jetpack compose so I want install Android Studio Canary Please tell me that can I Convert my Current Android Studio to Canary or I've to delete it and install Canary Version.
and Another Question is that my Android Studio 4.1.0 Projects will be opened with Canary or I've to Keep both in my Laptop.

Comment: Mark my answer as accepted if it solves your problem.

Comment: it didn't work, after clicking check now it redirected to canary download page

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can update your existing IDE to `canary` version:

`Setting` -> `Appearance and behavior` -> `System settings` -> `Updates`

Change your channel from `stable` (or whatever it is) to `canary` channel. Click `check now` and confirm it. This way it installs the latest canary version for you. Also, you can open Android Studio 4.1.0 projects in the `canary` version.